# Windows Phone app's icon not changing

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, emulation, device-emulation

I am extremely close to publishing my Windows Phone app. However, even though I changed the ApplicationIcon and Background images, the Windows Phone emulator doesn't use them.

Any ideas of why this is not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try uninstalling your app from the emulator then stop and restart it before finally deploying again. Seems to get cached sometimes.

Comment: Yeah, I was just about to try that when I unpinned it and bam! it worked again.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I figured it out.

I needed to unpin the app from the Start screen, then repin it.

Hope this helps someone.